# To see the types of login variables in PHP's sessions

Tags: php, session

**How can you see the type of variables: POST, GET, cookie, other?, after running `var_dump($_REQUEST)`?**

I run the following

```
 start_session();
 --- other code here --
 var_dump($_REQUEST);
```

It gives me

> array(3) { ["login"]=>  string(0) "" ["sid"]=>  string(32)
>   "b3408f5ff09bfc10c5b8fdeea5093d3e"
>   ["PHPSESSID"]=>  string(32)
>   "b3408f5ff09bfc10c5b8fdeea5093d3e" }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question.  Did you try:

```
var_dump($_POST);
var_dump($_COOKIE);
var_dump($_SESSION);
```

etc?

`$_REQUEST` is a different variable than `$_POST` and the others.  Was there something specific you are trying to see?

Comment: Thank you for your answer! - I asked the question because I am not sure about the type of cookie my session in is stored, either locally or externally.

Answer (score 1):

If by "the type of variables: POST, GET, cookie, other?" you mean "are the variables in `$_REQUEST`" coming from `$_GET`, `$_POST`, `$_COOKIE`, or environnement", I don't think there is a way : you will have to check inside those yourself...

And, btw, you'll have to do that taking into account the order that PHP uses those to populate `$_REQUEST` ; it is configured by this directive : http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.variables-order

But, still, why not work with `$_GET`, `$_POST` and others directly ?

Would probably be much more easier...

Answer (score 1):

A neat little function to prettily print out a variable's contents:

```
function debugVar($var)
{
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($var);
    echo '</pre>';
}

debugVar($_GET);
debugVar($_POST);
debugVar($blah);
```

On that note, do you literally mean, for example, what 'type' is `$_GET`? If so then the answer is **array**.

Answer (score 0):

To look at the specific array you can do this

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($_GET);
print_r($_POST);
echo "</pre>";
```

The pre tag is just to make it look nice. 
To access each of those do this.

```
$var = $_GET['paramName'];
```

Likewise with the other Super Arrays.